# PHP form on function with SQL request

Tags: php, sql, forms, request

I have this function on my php:

```
function getLastMatchs($nb) {
    try
    {
    $db = new PDO(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        die('connexion failed: '.$e->getMessage());
    }
    $i=0;
        $get5tmatchs = $db->query('SELECT wid, lid, date, cwid, clid FROM `match`');
        while ($nb<$i)
        {
            $data5matchs = $get5tmatchs->fetch();
            echo '<tr>
                    <td>'.$data5matchs['wid'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data5matchs['lid'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data5matchs['cwid'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data5matchs['clid'].'</td>';
                    echo '<td>'.$data5matchs['date'].'</td>
                    <br>
                </tr>';
        $i++;
        }
}
```

And my form is:

```
echo '<form action="index.php" method="post">
                <h3>My question......</h3>
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="nbmatchs" />
                    <input type="submit" value="ok" />
                </p>
                </form>';
        echo getLastMatchs('nbmatchs');
```

How can i do for show nbmatch time the guys want my table ?
When i do now, nothing happen.
Thanks for your help

PS: For exemple i tape 5, i can see 5 time the tabe i have put in my function.

Comment: How can i do for show nb the guys want my table ? what does that mean ?

Answer (score 0):

What you indended to accomplish (as far I understood) to allow a visitor enter a numer and then submit it after what some "matches" data it shown. The number visitor entered acts as a limiter.

1. Where do you get your POST variables? You have placed a function below the form with an input value of string 'nbmatchs'. I guess you wanted to submit the form and get the 'nbmatches' value and then apply it to the SQL query for filtering. The way you have done it doesn't work. You have action attribute on your form element set to index.php. That's where we are going to submit the form data. So we need to have a way to get the submitted POST variables. We do it like this:

```
$nbmatchs = $_POST['nbmatchs'];
```

Never trust data client has given you. As we know that it must a number let's do a check on it:

```
$nbmatches = is_numeric(trim($_POST['nbmatchs'])) ? $_POST['nbmatchs'] : 1;
```

Above we checked if the data client has given really is a number. If it is we'll assign this nubmer to variable $nbmatches. If the data client has given is not a number (eg. some string) we assign number 1 to the variable. At this point we may end the script execution a let the visitor know he must enter a number but we just assign 1 to the variable if anything seems suspicious. After that we can submit this variable to the function getLastMatchs which takes the variable and assigns it to the SQL query as a results limiter. Assuming that all the code will be in one file 'index.php' you should have the following code:

```
<?php

function getLastMatchs($nbmatches) {

    try{
        $db = new PDO(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die('connexion failed: '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    try {
        $select = $db->prepare('SELECT wid, lid, date, cwid, clid FROM `match` LIMIT '.$nbmatches.';');  
        $select->execute();
        $results = $select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo "<span style='color:red'>".$ex->getMessage()."</span></p>";  
    }

    echo '<table>';

    foreach($results as $result){
        $output = '<tr>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$result['wid'].'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$result['lid'].'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$result['cwid'].'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$result['clid'].'</td>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$result['date'].'</td>';
        $output = '</tr>';

        echo $output;
    }

    echo '</table>';

}

if(isset($_POST['nbmatchs'])){
    $nbmatches = is_numeric(trim($_POST['nbmatchs'])) ? $_POST['nbmatchs'] : 1;
    getLastMatchs($nbmatches);
}

?>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <h3>My question......</h3>
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="nbmatchs" />
        <input type="submit" value="ok" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Let me know if this works the way you wanted.

Comment: iget this error: Call to undefined function isNumeric() in

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake. I wrote PHP's function name wrong. Instead of `isNumeric` it should be `is_numeric`. I applied the fix to the code above.

Comment: If you got a solution to your problem please accept the post as an answer by clicking on the corresponding button.

Comment: i have this:  Undefined variable: data5matchs in

Comment: OK again my mistake. Fixed it. In the foreach loop I left the current cycle's variable to `$data5matchs`. Instead it should have been `$result` as declared in foreach's parenthesis. Now it should work. Let me know if you have any problems with this.